# Is dating haram? is halal dating a thing?

Tags: halal-haram

I have looked it up before, wether dating is haram or not, and have got very mixed opinions. Is it haram to date as a muslim?, and if so is it halal dating?

Answer (score 2):

Dating in Islam for the sake of having fun with the opposite sex, without having a proper and legal Islamic marriage is consider as forbidden (Haram).

Al-Israa' (17:32) :

> **"Nor come nigh to adultery: for it is a shameful (deed) and an evil,**
>   **opening the road (to other evils)."**

The main reason Islam forbids dating is to protect both parties from any kind of sexual lust (Zina).

However, meeting up for further recognition for the sake of finding a suitable spouse is allowed (Halal) with the present of the girl's mahram.

Comment: said, "However, meeting up for further recognition for the sake of finding a suitable spouse is allowed (Halal) with the present of the girl's mahram." what if you have no male mahram's at all?